# Test against emptiness fails if number is 0

Tags: javascript

For some reason, my boss changed the data I get in my JS, so, if once I received strings, now I can receive strings or numbers (from 0 to n). There was no problem until today, when I discovered the old code blocks when the number to test is exactly 0.

The reason is this code:

```
if(myObject.getData()) {
    ...
}
else {
    //here's where I go
}
```

`getData()` returns strings and numbers BUT when the number is `0`, the `if` test takes it for a Boolean value and the result is always `false`, while two lines later, inside the curly braces, I need the number `0` to send it to a server.

What's the best way to check if data is not `null`, not `false`, not `""`, not even Boolean, and "preserve" my `0`?

Comment: `myObject.getData()!=undefined` should work

Comment: try `parseInt(myObject.getData())`?

Comment: because 0 is a falsey value....

Comment: @epascarello: ok, I understood this, I was looking for a good solution   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing your requirements it appears you want only non-empty strings and numbers. If that assumption is correct you could use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and do something like:

```
var data = myObject.getData();

if((typeof data === 'string' && data !== '') || typeof data === 'number') {
  //...
}
else{
  //here's where I go
}
```

This approach has two key benefits:

1. It is explicit in what the input format should be so therefore is self-documenting.
2. It guards against any future input type modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce an OR into your `if` statement to check whether it's the numeric value `0` using the strict equality operator (`===`):

```
var data = myObject.getData();
if ( data || data === 0 )
```

Some test cases:

```
data = ""           // false
data = false        // false
data = undefined    // false
data = 0            // true
data = 1            // true
data = "test"       // true
```

Comment: This was my very first idea but I thought it was not very elegant and I did another thing, less elegant too: I converted all data to strings and used trim() to test if they returned a non empty string

Comment: @3000 you don't need to do that. The first part of this `if` statement will filter out all falsey values (including the empty string); the second part will then check if the falsey value is exactly equal to `0`.

Comment: @3000 A concern with this solution (and it might be one if your boss changes the input once again) is that if any object was passed it would accept that as a truthy value. This would be a bit odd but given the input type has already been modified once it might be wise to guard against it.